# Передать и получить символ возврата каретки в GET запросе

Tags: c#, http, get, rest, swagger

В swagger-интерфейсе в Get запрос передаю строку "**area1\rarea2\rarea3**" получаю "**area1\\rarea2\\rarea3**" :(

Как передать в swagger возврат каретки "\r" и получить его?

*Подозреваю что это какая-то особенность HTTP/Браузера/.. которая мне не известна или баг в swagger.

*UPD1 через POSTMAN такой проблемы нет.

Браузер Chrome
Проект на C#, 2017 студия, ASP NET MVC 6.0
Swagger 2.0 подключен через Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Answer (score 1):

Для передачи спецсимволов в GET запросе их нужно экранировать при помощи URL Encode.

Для `\r` это будет `%0D`, соответственно передавать нужно `area1%0Darea2%0Darea3`.

В .NET для этого преобразования можно использовать [`System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: да это первая мысль что пришла в голову: пробовали не работает :(
браузер в строке адреса делает авто-конвертацию и экранирование не срабатывает.